# Inequality for definite integral.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

In a proof in my class we used the following inequality: $$\left| \int_0^{\varepsilon}te^{ut}\,du\right|\le |\varepsilon| |t|(e^{\varepsilon_0t}+e^{-\varepsilon_0t})\quad \forall |\varepsilon| <\varepsilon_0.$$However, I'm not quite sure how we got that inequality so I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exponential function is strictly increasing then for any $|\epsilon|<\epsilon_0$ we have that
$$e^{ut}\leq e^{|ut|}\leq e^{|\epsilon| |t|}\leq e^{\epsilon_0 |t|} = \max\{e^{\epsilon_0t},e^{-\epsilon_0t}\}\leq e^{\epsilon_0 t}+e^{-\epsilon_0t} $$
Hence
\begin{align*}\Big|\int_0^\epsilon te^{tu} du\Big| &\leq sign(\epsilon)\int_0^\epsilon |t|e^{ut}du\leq sign(\epsilon)\int_0^\epsilon |t|(e^{\epsilon_0 t}+e^{-\epsilon_0t})du\\
&= [|t|(e^{\epsilon_0 t}+e^{-\epsilon_0t})] sign(\epsilon)\int_0^\epsilon du\\ 
&= |t|(e^{\epsilon_0 t}+e^{-\epsilon_0t}) sign(\epsilon)\epsilon = |t||\epsilon|(e^{\epsilon_0 t}+e^{-\epsilon_0t})
\end{align*}

Comment: Why do you still get the first inequality when you multiply $\text{sign}(\varepsilon)$?

Comment: Is it to deal with the fact that $\varepsilon$ can be negative?

Comment: @statman exactly. The inequality is because we do not know the sign of $t$. So at best we have $t\leq |t|$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left| \int_0^{\varepsilon}te^{ut}\,du\right| \le |t|  \int_0^{\varepsilon}|e^{ut}|\,du  = |t| \int_0^{\varepsilon}e^{ut}\,du $$

Consider $$f(\varepsilon) := \int_0^\varepsilon e^{tu} \ du.$$ This is a convex function and for the fundamental theorem of calculus  $f'(\varepsilon) = e^{\varepsilon t}$.

Fix $\varepsilon_0 > 0$, then for all $0\le \varepsilon \le \varepsilon_0$ you have $f(0) \ge f(\varepsilon) + f'(\varepsilon)(0-\varepsilon)$ so

$$\int_0^\varepsilon e^{tu}\ du \le \varepsilon \ e^{\varepsilon t} \le \varepsilon \ e^{\varepsilon_0 t}$$

Concluding

$$\left| \int_0^{\varepsilon}te^{ut}\,du\right| \le |t| \varepsilon \ e^{\varepsilon_0t} \le |t| |\varepsilon| \left( \ e^{\varepsilon_0t} + e^{-\varepsilon_0t}\right)$$

Since in the last passage I just added a strictly positive term.

Comment: We $|\epsilon|< \epsilon_0$, so you are using a different $\epsilon_0$ than the one given in the problem.

Comment: I fixed that step.